# Install high-end applications one layer above the OS

Tags: virtualization, operating-systems

I'd like to install high-end applications such as databases, servers and IDE tools one layer above the OS.

Virtual machines come to mind, but my host OS runs just fine and I don't want to waste the resources by installing another OS on top of it. Still, I want a functionality similar to that.

I want those applications running only when needed without compromising performance. For example, databases use services that start with the system, but those should be disabled when not in use.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you want programs not to consume resources when not needed, couldn't you just quit them?

Comment: Maybe he is talking about additional services running permanently in background.

Comment: For example, I am using database means by default it uses many services which will start whenever system starts, but when I install my applications above one layer, I will have more control over my applications. So my system will have normal boot, but when needed I need to work on those applications.

Comment: Yes nixda many high end applications have background services, when we disabled those we need a restart for working them perfectly.

Comment: @HariharanRam: If you have two licenses of Windows it is possible to install two copies at the same time with the choice of which one to boot into. Honestly though I don't think you need to go to the trouble of something like this though, since unused background services rarely consume much resources. If your computer really can't handle them then you should think about upgrading it.

Comment: Do you mean something like VMware ThinApp, which watches the initial installation to see where files are put and registry entries etc. and then creates an encapsulated executable type file that you would deploy to any PC after that? I have used VMware Thinapp inside a freshly installed VM and then run the install of the program you want to encapsulate. Maybe that will work? Not sure how it will function with server type apps that also use services/daemons but worth a shot?

Comment: @James My system is able to handle the services, but it nearly takes 2-3 minutes for loading those background services at startup. So when I want to check a simple mail I have to wait for extra 3 mins. So only I am looking for a solution and also keeping a layer above os will give good abstraction for separating my work.

Comment: I want a similar functionality like @james mentioned but without two different installations.

Comment: @Karan It is a helpful suggestions. Will I able to use different accounts with different services running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but it nearly takes 2-3 minutes for loading those background
>   services at startup

You can set them to **Automatic (Delayed Start)** (or perhaps even **Manual**) instead of **Automatic** in `Start / run / services.msc`

You cannot automatically set different services to launch based on the user logging in. You can change the user account a service uses to start up, but it will still start up with the system if it's set to **Automatic** (it'll just run with different credentials).

What you can do is set the services to **Manual**, then add a batch file to the Startup folder or `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key which will launch the services you want for that particular user using the `net start` or `sc start` commands.

Note that the services will stay running even after logging off. If that's a problem, you can go to `Start / Run / gpedit.msc / User Configuration / Windows Settings / Scripts (Logon/Logoff)` and add scripts that will stop the services started for that user.